# Could not copy the file "..\HiQPdf.dep" because it was not found

Tags: pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

I get this build error after trying to use HTML to PDF Converter Library for .NET. I copy over the dll, dep and xml files from the ZIPped folder downloaded from the website but when I compile my code, the HiQPdf.dep disappears.

The [FAQs from the website](http://www.hiqpdf.com/FAQs.aspx) say to change the execute permissions of the HiQPdf.dep file but after i do this, it still doesn't work.

How can i get rid of this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved this by changing the execute permissions on the HiQPdf.dep file and then changing it to read-only. I don't see how this is a stable or logical fix but it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by just removing & re-adding the dll.